# Best Graphics over X11 Forwarding

Tags: centos, x11, gnome, graphics, forwarding

I am currently using Exceed to handle individual X windows being displayed back to my Windows machine and this works flawlessly.  I'm using Windows as my Window manager, but I have also experimented with various "X Windows Managers" (i.e., `fluxbox`, `twm`, `mwm`, `gnome-wm`) to no avail.

The issue I'm having is the graphics being displayed back on individual applications is poor compared to what I am seeing when forwarding a full gnome-Desktop/gnome-session over the same Exceed connection.  In fact, if I run an instance of gnome-session over X11 I am able to launch applications with their standard a high quality "look" as directly connected to the machine.  However, if I just use a window manager and display back single applications (not a full desktop/session) the quality reverts to a poorer more basic design.

Is there anyway to launch `gnome-session` against a single application vice having to create a whole desktop instance?  Or a way to use its graphics engine to render the application as it would be in a normal session/desktop environment?  I thought the `gnome-wm` would do the trick, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get it to load a GTK theme (the default gnome one is `adawita`)

You can try `GTK_THEME=Adwaita` then the command.

Have you also looked at using `x2go`? It often gives better performance.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I even tried with a simple app, gedit, but could not get any appearance change to the window/application using `GTK_THEME`

Comment: Also forgot to mention I can't do x2go, as the Windows client is unavailable for use; Exceed has been deemed our corporate solution. Should also mention running CentOS 6 with Gnome 2.